# Sparql about dbpedia:World_Wide_Web

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to the semantic web and I'm trying to figure out how to write a SPARQL query to extract from dbpedia everything about a particular subject. Not just it's proprieties, but also everything related to it.

I'm not even sure how to start such a query.

I would like to get all triples about the World Wide Web.

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o 
WHERE  {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  ?s ?p dbpedia:World_Wide_Web  

  #  FILTER( lang(?s) = "en" )   -- doesn't work with filter

}Limit 100
```

This only returns some triples with a owl:sameAs predicate

Can you help me?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "everything related to it".  RDF is about triples.  The only description of a thing is the triples that it's the subject or object of.   Your query is just asking for all the subjects that have `dbpedia:World_Wide_Web` as an object.

Comment: Your filter is working just fine.  However, only literals have languages, and literals can't be the subjects of triples in RDF, so you're not going to get any results.

Comment: I want to get things about programming languages used for web and people who developed the WWW and events for the WWW... stuff like that

Comment: You can browse dbpedia data, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/page/World_Wide_Web.  What is it that you're actually trying to get out?  Note that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  What are sort of expected results you're looking for?

Comment: i want to know how i can get from < dbpedia:Tim_Bernards_Lee  dbpedia-owl:knownFor dbpedia:WWW > to  thigngs about TBL for example

Comment: You can browse the page for Tim Berners-Lee at http://dbpedia.org/page/Tim_Berners-Lee.  I don't see any knownFor property, though I do see:  "is dbpedia-owl:developer of 
dbpedia:WorldWideWeb".  Do you have some source that includes such a `knownFor` link?

Comment: No sorry. I got that wrong. It was on WWW resource: And it was the other way around. WWW known for TBL

Comment: That's OK.  We're getting somewhere now;  I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the triples that have `dbpedia:World_Wide_Web` as their subject or object with a query like this (this only gives 1000, of course).  For any objects that *are* literals, we can restrict their language value:

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {
  values ?web { dbpedia:World_Wide_Web }
  { ?web ?p ?o bind( ?web as ?s ) } union
  { ?s ?p ?web bind( ?web as ?o ) }

  # for literal objects, take only English ones
  filter( !isLiteral(?o) || langMatches(lang(?o),'en') )
}
limit 1000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?s%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20?web%20%7B%20dbpedia%3aWorld_Wide_Web%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?web%20?p%20?o%20bind%28%20?web%20as%20?s%20%29%20%7D%20union%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?s%20?p%20?web%20bind%28%20?web%20as%20?o%20%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20#%20for%20literal%20objects,%20take%20only%20English%20ones%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20!isLiteral%28?o%29%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28?o%29,%27en%27%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%201000%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This includes results like the following, which seems to align with what you mentioned in the comments:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/World_Wide_Web  http://dbpedia.org/property/company  http://dbpedia.org/resource/CERN
http://dbpedia.org/resource/World_Wide_Web  http://dbpedia.org/property/inventor  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tim_Berners-Lee
```

That will produce a *lot* of results, so you might want to restrict the properties that you can use.  You *should* be able to do the following, but on the current DBpedia endpoint, it causes an error.

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {
  values ?web { dbpedia:World_Wide_Web }
  values ?p   { rdf:type dbpedia-owl:abstract }

  { ?web ?p ?o bind( ?web as ?s ) } union
  { ?s ?p ?web bind( ?web as ?o ) }
}
limit 1000
```

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Internal error: sparp_gp_attach_filter_cbk(): attempt to attach a filter with used variable

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> select ?s ?p ?o where {
  values ?web { dbpedia:World_Wide_Web }
  values ?p   { rdf:type dbpedia-owl:abstract }

  { ?web ?p ?o bind( ?web as ?s ) } union
  { ?s ?p ?web bind( ?web as ?o ) }
}
limit 1000
```

Instead, as a workaround, you can do this:

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {
  values ?web { dbpedia:World_Wide_Web }

  { ?web ?p ?o bind( ?web as ?s ) }
  union
  { ?s ?p ?web bind( ?web as ?o ) }

  filter( ?p in (rdf:type, dbpedia-owl:abstract ))  ###
}
limit 1000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?s%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20?web%20%7B%20dbpedia%3aWorld_Wide_Web%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?web%20?p%20?o%20bind%28%20?web%20as%20?s%20%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20union%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?s%20?p%20?web%20bind%28%20?web%20as%20?o%20%29%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20?p%20in%20%28rdf%3atype,%20dbpedia-owl%3aabstract%20%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%201000%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Woow! Thanks a lot Joshua! I'd never thought of it like this. Can i also insert a list of predicates i want to allow? Would this be like values ?p { rdf:type, dc:terms/alternative } bind { what you did } ?

Comment: awesome! how can i limit a query only to several ( a list of ) proprieties that i type?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! If you're ever in Romania i'm gonna get you a beer! YOu've helped me a lot. I'll try to see why this doesnt work and i;ll post the answer if i find out. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @AlexDoro I updated the answer.  The simple answer of `values ?p { p1 p2 ... }` should work, but DBpedia's endpoint rejects it for some reason.  You can do ``filter( ?p in (p1, p2, ...) )` instead.  Hopefully the `filter` is as efficient as the `values` would be.