# SPARQL Jena iterative to get results about more subjects

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I'm trying to get information about some concepts on DBpedia. I found out how to get 1, but for more it fails. I've  been told filtering should help, but the processing time is too long and i get timeouts.

The thing i can't do is VALUES ?s { dbpedia:Facebook dbpedia:Google }

So I've looked for an alternative way, but it still isn;t working. Here's where I'm now:

```
public static String concepts[] = { "Facebook", "Google" };

    public static String getQuery(String concept) {
        return "prefix dbpediaowl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"
                + " prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"
                + " prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                + " prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + " PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"
                + " prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"
                + " select ?s ?p ?o where { "
                + " values ?web {  dbpedia:"
                + "Facebook"
                + " } "
                + " { ?web ?p ?o bind( ?web as ?s ) } " + " union "
                + " { ?s ?p ?web bind( ?web as ?o ) } " + " filter( ?p in ( "
                + "dbpprop:available, " + "dbpprop:company, "
                + "dbpprop:inventor, " + "dbpedia-owl:foundedBy, "
                + "dbpedia-owl:subsidiary, " + "dbpprop:foundation, "
                + "dbpprop:founder, " + "dbpprop:industry, "
                + "dbpprop:programmingLanguage, " + "dbpedia-owl:successor )) ";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OutputStream os;
        PrintStream printStream;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/alex/Desktop/data.txt");
            printStream = new PrintStream(os);
            printStream.println("am scris");
            for (int i = 0; i < concepts.length; i++) {
                printStream.println(i+ " concept");
                Query query = QueryFactory.create(getQuery(concepts[i])); 

                QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
                        "http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql", query);
                ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect();

                while (results.hasNext()) {
                    printStream.println(results.nextSolution().toString());
                }

            }

            printStream.close();
            os.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }

    }
```

For one concept at a time, in the SPARQL it works fine, but I need to call about 50 of them. So I need to know how i can do it programatically. Also, it would be great if you could help me select the predicates as well ( without the filtering ) because I also need to allow about 30-40 of them.

Thanks a lot! Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I thought we'd solved the problem with `VALUES ?s { dbpedia:Facebook dbpedia:Google }` in your previous question, [Sparql about dbpedia:World_Wide_Web](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21002440/1281433).  Instead of doing `values ?s { dbpedia:Facebook dbpedia:Google }`, you can use `filter( ?s in (dbpedia:Facebook, dbpedia:Google) }`. This works just fine for subjects and properties.  E.g., if you wanted to get the English abstracts and labels for Google and Facebook, you could use a query like this:

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {
  ?s ?p ?o
  filter( ?s in (dbpedia:Google, dbpedia:Facebook) )
  filter( ?p in (rdfs:label, dbpedia-owl:abstract) )
  filter( !isLiteral(?o) || langMatches(lang(?o),"en") ) 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?s%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20?p%20?o%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20?s%20in%20%28dbpedia:Google,%20dbpedia:Facebook%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20?p%20in%20%28rdfs:label,%20dbpedia-owl:abstract%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20!isLiteral%28?o%29%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28?o%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now, if you can get rid of that `union` (which you might be able to do, if you're really just looking for the values of certain properties from certain subjects), then you actually can use the `values` blocks in the way that you'd like to.  (Really, I think the problematic behavior seen in your other question is due to a DBpedia bug;  I think you should be able to use `values` and `union` together.)  That is, to select non-literals, and literals with an English language tag for some specified properties, you can do:

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {
  values ?s { dbpedia:Google dbpedia:Facebook }
  values ?p { rdfs:label dbpedia-owl:abstract }
  ?s ?p ?o
  filter( !isLiteral(?o) || langMatches(lang(?o),"en") ) 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?s%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20?s%20%7B%20dbpedia:Google%20dbpedia:Facebook%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20values%20?p%20%7B%20rdfs:label%20dbpedia-owl:abstract%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?s%20?p%20?o%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20!isLiteral%28?o%29%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28?o%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: problem with filters is they tend to work slower and DBpedia gives me timeouts. I found a better endpoint thats mirroring DBpedia but it still has its limitations and i need about 30-40-50 resources checked.

Comment: @AlexDoro If you're just querying for the values of certain properties, you should be able to get rid of the `union` and use `values`, right?  Does that still have the timeout issue?